# Run a webapp on Tomcat without using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

I've developped a Maven webapp on Eclipse with a MySQL database. I use tomcat on Eclipse to simulate a local server and use my app.

Now that it's finished I want to use my webapp without using Eclipse to launch the tomcat server.

How do I proceed ?

I've tried to export my project to a WAR file and put it in the webapp folder in the tomcat folder and start the startup.bat file but when I try to access my app it doesn't work.
Do I need to configure the xml files in the tomcat folder first ?

Can you help me please ?

(my app runs on port 8082)

Comment: Look at the logs to find out why "it doesn't work", and draw conclusions. With such a vague description of the problem, we can't help.

Comment: you mean the logs in the tomcat logs folder ? the folder is empty

Comment: when you are starting tomcat using startup.bat does it say "Deployment of web application archive xyz.war  has finished in **ms" ?

Comment: no it doesn't say anything. Nothing happens.